# Android bottom elements not showing

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have problem with my layout element. They are being displayed in mobile phone but neither in Genymotion or Android Emulator.

Two Buttons are not being displayed at the bottom.

Here is my code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="vitrine.ndex.com.vitrine.fragments.FavouriteFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/cartButton"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/historyButton"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/header_panel_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/favouriteShopListView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need couple of changes in Layout.

1. Wrap the whole `RelativeLayout` inside `ScrollView`
2. Take out `ListView` out of `RelativeLayout` and put it in a Layout which is outside `ScrollView`

Comment: Putting layout with `ListView` inside `ScrollView` is not good practice.

Comment: Could you please, explain, I should change which layout elements?

Comment: @poss: Ah  ! I just missed there is a ListView too. Yes, true. I updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: I have just tested your code, you are only missing `</FrameLayout>` at the end... On Genymotion and device I can see the buttons.

Comment: @FiN: I am assuming that is a typo by OP

Comment: I add </FrameLayout> but nothing change. Maybe this problem in Android Studio? Because 3 hours ago 2 buttons was visible at the bottom and.